# How to disable Path Traversal Attack on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel web that serve some file for authenticated user only but somehow hacker can get my .env file by Path Traversal. Here is my route under middleware auth group

```
Route::get('storage/{filename?}/download/',function($filename){        
    $basepath = storage_path($filename);
    $path = realpath($basepath);
    try {
        if ($path !== false && substr($path, 0, strlen($basepath)) == $basepath){
            $response = response()->download($path);
            return $response;
        }
        
    } catch (\Throwable $err) {
        abort(404);
    }
})->where('filename','(.*)');
Route::get('storage/{filename?}',function($filename){  
    $basepath = storage_path($filename);
    $path = realpath($basepath);
    try {
        if ($path !== false && substr($path, 0, strlen($basepath)) == $basepath){
            $response = response()->file($path);
            return $response;
        }
        
    } catch (\Throwable $err) {
        abort(404);
    }
})->where('filename','(.*)');
```

I write this route after reading an article from [here](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/laravel-path-traversal-guide-examples-and-prevention/) but I dont know how to test if my app is free from path traversal attack. Is it enough only configuring my route like this or any additional setting? the only accessible storage is `storage/app/files`

Answer (score 0):

This is still not safe. example:

```
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.4.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $basepath = storage_path('../.env');
=> "/usr/local/var/www/site-example/storage/../.env"
>>> $path = realpath($basepath);
=> "/usr/local/var/www/site-example/.env"
```

Just follow the guide you mentioned. `basename` will strip the directories attached.

```
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.4.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $fileName = basename('../.env');
=> ".env"
>>> $basepath = storage_path($fileName);
=> "/usr/local/var/www/site-example/storage/.env"
>>> $path = realpath($basepath);
=> false
>>>
```

false is returned if the file does not exist in the storage dir.

```
>> $fileName = basename('../.env');
=> ".env"
>>> $basepath = storage_path($fileName);
=> "/usr/local/var/www/example-site/storage/.env"
>>> $path = realpath($basepath);
=> false
>>> $fileName = basename('../test-file.pdf');
=> "test-file.pdf"
>>> $basepath = storage_path($fileName);
=> "/usr/local/var/www/example-site/storage/test-file.pdf"
>>> $path = realpath($basepath);
=> "/usr/local/var/www/example-site/storage/test-file.pdf"
>>>
```

Comment: I've tried with basename but it not returned full path so it will always thro an error even if fullpath is valid, as i mentioned above the app should accept filename parameter on route and the if return the response

Comment: It only returns false if the file does not exist. ill update to show.

Comment: imagine url like this a.com/storage/app/files/CJ2-96037-0048/sph.jpg
with my route definition $filename will be "app/files/CJ2-96037-0048/sph.jpg" and basename will be sph.jpg right? it will only work if sph.jpg is under storage folder directly

Comment: and that in and on itself is not safe.

Comment: so what is the best solution?

Comment: There is no solution if you are allowing users to traverse directories. If you know they are a set amount of directories you could conditional check them or allow select inputs to allow the directories however any time you allow users to traverse your directories you are introducing a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a path check against storage path to avoid path traversal attacks after finding realpath of the requested file:

Like:

```
$fileName = "../.env";
$filePath = realpath(storage_path($fileName));
$storagePath = storage_path();

if (!$filePath) {
    abort(404, "Not Found");
}

if (strpos($filePath, $storagePath) !== 0) {
    abort(403, "Forbidden");
}
```

Comment: However it's unable to avoid local traversal attacks using this method. Subdirectories inside storage were still vulnerable.